# if I want to check the value is string or int in php

Tags: php

I have a **string value** from database.
I need to check if this value is an integer or a string.
I have tried `is_int` and `is_numeric`, but both of them are not what I need.

`is_int` always return false if the value is type of String while `is_numeric` return true if my the value contain number.

What I am using is `preg_match('/^\d+$/',$value)`, and, I am looking for a simple solution in this case.

Comment: integers may also have a minus sign

Comment: `is_int()` and `is_numeric()` should be working for numbers... You are probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In my case, all value are positive integer or string contain integer. Anyway, thank you for your kindly reminder

Comment: @Veger is_int() should not, while is_numeric() will allow floating point numbers too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$stringIsAnInteger = ctype_digit($string);
```

[`ctyped_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype-digit)

Comment: Thanks, it works. A further question, is there any simple way to handle value with *decimal point* and/or minus sign?

Comment: @MichaelLaw `is_numeric()` should do it.

Comment: O....I misunderstand the manual's example that String value with number will always pass...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctype_digit()` — Check for numeric character(s). Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.

**Example 1**

```
<?php
$strings = array('1820.20', '10002', 'wsl!12');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_digit($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all digits.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Above will output

```
The string 1820.20 does not consist of all digits.
The string 10002 consists of all digits.
The string wsl!12 does not consist of all digits.
```

**Example 2**

```
<?php

$numeric_string = '42';
$integer        = 42;

ctype_digit($numeric_string);  // true
ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)

is_numeric($numeric_string);   // true
is_numeric($integer);          // true
?>
```

Comment: I wanted to provide few examples so it easier for anyone who reads understand since all the information are in one page. don't have to travel through urls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, @KingCrunch answer the question first, therefore I accepted that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find your way the best one.
I see nothing complex in a simple regex, so, in your place I wouldn't look for simpler.

Speaking of complexity, do not limit yourself just to the caller code.
It could be as short as a single function call. But you cannot be sure about *underlying* code, which can be enormously complex and - an important thing - have some issues, like every function named here does.

While your own solution either simple and robust.

Update:
All the remarks saying "do not use regexp where simple string function can be used for the performance blah-blah" are directly from the last century.

- it doesn't mean "do not use regexp even if none of string functions suits you"
- it's XXI at the moment, and computers are blazingly fast, especially in such easy matters as text parsing. Such a simple regexp will **never** be **a bottleneck** of your application. So, there is not a single reason to prefer a string function over regexp in terms of performance optimization. On a **real life app** you will never ever notice (or measure) any difference.

Comment: In `preg_match`, there is a tip said *Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.*, therefore, I think if there is a native function, it will be better than using regex.